# Override how Entity Framework connects to a database?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sqlconnection

I would like to be able to "manually" manage how Entity Framework connects to my SQL database.

What I have in mind is something along the lines of overriding a function that makes a connection to the database.

```
public override SqlConnection getNewConnection()
{
    // return the connection to be used
}
```

Is this possible?

**Update:** Here's what I've written based on the answer I've received:

```
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection("metadata=res://*/Models.ADLEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.ADLEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADLEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=mycatalog;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;");
entities = new Models.ModswebEntities(connection);
```

I composed this code by copying the connection string from web.config that was generated by the VS wizard that generated the EDMX object.  However, when I run this code, I get an error that says `Keyword not supported: 'data source'`.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in the DbContext constructor where you can pass in a DbConnection and whether or not the context owns it:

```
public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection,bool contextOwnsConnection)
```

or, if you're using an ObjectContext you can [pass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738714.aspx) in an [EntityConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.aspx) in the constructor:

```
public ObjectContext( EntityConnection connection)
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I have gone thru the constructors and properties for the entities object in my program and I don't see any reference to a thing called DbContext?  How do I access that?

Comment: I assumed you were using a DbContext base for your connection to the database.. are you doing it code first or model first, and what version of EF are you using?

Comment: From my web.config, it looks like my project is using EF4.4.  As for my database object, I used the VS Wizard to create an EDMX from an existing SQL database; definitely *not* code first.

As for my connection, the problem is this, I have to use Windows Authentication to connect, but I need to be certain that the system impersonates a particular account for the connection, but not for anything else.

Comment: There should be an overloaded constructor that the designer creates.. Something like YourContextName(EntityConnection) which you can use to pass in a SqlConnection and metadata workspace.  If you look in the Cs, it will be in the Constructors region

Comment: I've written some code based on your answer, but it isn't working.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're just wanting to pass in a connection string - why dont you just pass that in?  You could save the connection string in your web.config, and then use that overload YourContext(string ConnectionstringName) instead of going through the hoops of making an entityconnection

Comment: That doesn't work for me because I need to control the impersonation context.  I think that the only way to do that would be to manually set up an impersonation context when the connection is established.

Comment: Ah - [this example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/dd7b1c41-e428-4e29-ab83-448d3f529ba4/) should help you create the Entity Connection